# Windows 7 freezes on bootup

Tags: windows-7, boot

My computer is a Dell Inspiron 1545 laptop, with Windows 7 (SP1) and a 64 bit architecture.

My problem is that the laptop freezes on boot up at the “Please Wait” screen and does not proceed to “Welcome” and completion of the boot. I had not installed any hardware immediately prior to the problem starting, nor any software, other than program updates.

I have a Windows Repair CD but when I boot from this, it tells me it can find no problems on starting up.

Dell has an on-line diagnostic programme but, again, this shows no starting problems.

When I press F8 on start up and select “Repair the Computer”, again there is no repair.

I have, of course, run a full malware scan with Microsoft Security Essentials, with no problem detected.

Before I describe the actions I have taken with msconfig, I should say at this stage that if the bootup freezes, the only way I can get back to normal operation, is to boot up in safe mode and then use system restore. On completion of restoring the computer to an earlier stage, all is well and the computer behaves perfectly. Provided I don’t turn the computer off all remains well. When I have finished work, I put the laptop into “Sleep” mode  and it restarts (without a boot, of course) and I carry on working normally. But unlike all other occasions I have used system restore, the “cure” is not permanent. As soon as I turn off and try to restart, once again the computer freezes. I have never known system restore to behave this way before. It seems to cure the problem, but only temporarily. Another strange phenomenon is that if I chose “Use Last Good Configuration” using the F8 procedure, usually the computer freezes as usual. But occasionally it proceeds to a good boot, but after a few minute the computer crashes and I have to go back to safe mode to effect a recovery.

I have joined the Microsoft forum, and put my problem up for discussion. I have had a couple of ideas from people there, but nothing that gets anywhere near solving the problem.

Now back to msconfig; I first selected “Selective Startup” and then disabled all startup programs. On restarting the computer it once again freezes. I conclude from this that it is not a startup program that is the problem. Now, I am reluctant to disable system services or use diagnostic startup in msconfig, since I have read that doing this removes all system restore points. And using system restore is the only way I can recover my computer and use it normally – provided I don’t turn it off, of course.

I could ignore the problem and never turn the computer off, but I would like to find an answer and fix it. I would prefer not to do a re-install. All ideas gratefully received.

Comment: It really sounds like a hardware problem which means that the HDD is to blame either that or a driver problem since safe mode doesn't load your drivers and a system restore point would mean that problem drive isn't loaded.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to **try for testing purposes** to fix the problem.

Please note that I do not want to be responsible for any data loss or other failure kind, so please back up your files before doing these actions:

1. make a bios update according to vendor's manual. go to step 2 if that doesn't work
2. download all of the drivers (that your PC uses) from vendors's site and install them again.
   note: don't restart your comp until all of them are installed. if that doesn't work go to step 3
3. scan your PC in offline USB mode with good offline scanner such as [Kaspersky rescue disk 10](http://support.kaspersky.com/viruses/rescuedisk)
   if no threat is found go to step 4
4. re install the windows

If you computer still doesn't work after all the steps then you can be sure is a hardware failure.
So all you can do is to take it to service for hardware repair.